# How to test for PCB ground being pulled up to 2V when connected to RS485

Tags: ground, oscilloscope, rs485, testing, production-testing

I am currently trying to find an easy way test to diagnose a problem on some of our PCBs where the ground of the PCB is being pulled up to 2V's.

***The Board***

Simple modular RS485 sensor board. The main components are RS485 Transciever (SN65HVD1780D Half Duplex), ATMega168PA, ADC and Monolithic Buck Switching Regulator. All inputs to the board have good filtering (TVS Diodes, EMI Chip Filters and ferrite beads). These PCBs are connected to other identical RS485 sensor boards.

***The Problem***

When connected to other sensor board modules this PCB causes others to fail or miss sensor readings. After investigation i found that while measuring the GND voltage with a scope with its ground connected to its own ground pin that GND was sitting at 2V. This currently gets through our test rig with flying colours as the RS485 comms seems to be unaffected when it is connected to a low number of similar RS485 modules.

The GND also only get's pulled up when the RS485 is connected. I am testing this mainly using an rs485 serial converter (BB-USPTL4-LS). I assume this is always the case when connected to any RS485 connection as we are seeing problems when connected to other equipment.

When the board is just powered with the RS485 disconnected the board looks like a normal board when looking at various signals on a scope.

***The Cause***

I am fairly certain that this is being caused by ESD damage to either the RS485 transceiver or the regulator. However I have not tried replacing either yet as I will then loose my only example of this fault.

***The Solution***

Currently I am looking at checking each one with an oscilliscope but this seems abit over complicated for some of the operators in production. I was unable to find any differences between a good board and a bad board using a multimeter looking at resistance between +ve and gnd etc.

If anyone is aware of a good way to batch test pcbs specifically a gnd issue like this one or any suggestions as to what might be causing an issue like this it would be much appreciated. Please let me know if you require any more information to answer.

Thanks

Comment: Is the board not working properly somehow? What makes you think this is an actual problem? Pulling the ground of a board up by 2V would normally take a huge amount of current so I suspect your measuring technique is showing something that's not really there.

Comment: It doesn't work when connected in a chain of other identical modules. It also causes the other modules to not work correctly. I have measured the ground on other working modules and the GND stays at 0V

Comment: What does the ground get pulled up relative to? The power supply? I think we need some sort of schematic to understand the issue as grounds are normally well connected together and difficult to get a 2V difference without something seriously wrong.

Comment: Relative to ground of the oscilliscope, I will try to coble together a basic schematic today.

Comment: How is the oscilloscope ground connected to your system?

Comment: beware of ground loops by scope probes! The shield box ties them all together and it's easy to make these thing happen